# Comparing xy coordinates in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I currently have a dataframe like this:

```
x        y       category
159.5    143.5   1
157.5    180.5   1
127.5    159.5   1
115.5    115.5   2
179.5    101.5   2
97.5     103.5   2
149.5    397.5   3
179.5    297.5   3
```

I'd like to compare each point against every other point in the dataframe. I want to get the difference in x and y (ie point 159.5, 143.5 to point 157.5,    180.5 would be a absolute difference of 2 in x and +37 in y)

I've tried to do this in multiple ways but I'm not coming close, as well as using too many for-loops which is too slow. I'm positive there's a dplyr/function way of doing this and it would be really helpful.

Here's my sample output goal (Not all filled out, but the general idea):

```
x        y        abs x-diff   y-diff  category            
159.5    143.5    0            0       1         (from 159.5    143.5)    
159.5    143.5    2            37      1         (from 157.5    180.5)
159.5    143.5    32           16      1         (from 127.5    159.5)
157.5    180.5    0            0       1         (from 157.5    180.5)
157.5    180.5    2            -37     1         (from 159.5    143.5)
157.5    180.5                         1
127.5    159.5    0            0       1
127.5    159.5                         1
127.5    159.5                         1
115.5    115.5    0           0        2         (from 115.5    115.5)
115.5    115.5    64          -14      2         (from 179.5    101.5)
115.5    115.5    18          -12      2         (from 97.5     103.5)
179.5    101.5    0           0        2
179.5    101.5                         2
179.5    101.5                         2
97.5     103.5    0           0        2
97.5     103.5                         2
97.5     103.5                         2
149.5    397.5    0           0        3
149.5    397.5                         3         
179.5    297.5    0           0        3
179.5    297.5                         3
```

There should of 3*3 (for cat. 1), 3*3 (for cat. 2) and 2*2 (for cat. 3), for a total of 22 rows.

EDITED: I've added a category variable. I've tried to modify the previous answers to get it to work, but I would like to compare the coordinates within each category. The other answers don't work for this added layer since it repeats the entire data frame n times, but it's more complicated for a group_by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar solution elsewhere.

```
diffing_function <- function(i) {
 d <- subset(df, df$category == i)
 R <- expand.grid(i1 = unique(d$id), i2 = unique(d$id))
 R$category <- i
 R$x1 <- d$x[match(R$i1, d$id)]
 R$y1 <- d$y[match(R$i1, d$id)]
 R$x2 <- d$x[match(R$i2, d$id)]
 R$y2 <- d$y[match(R$i2, d$id)]
 R$xdiff <- R$x2 - R$x1
 R$ydiff <- R$y2 - R$y1
 return(R)
}

results_list <- lapply(unique(df$category), diffing_function)
results_df <- do.call(rbind, results_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, in your sample output you are not consistent in desiring positive or negative values. For example,  `159.5 from 157.5 = 2`, while `159.5 from 190.5` and `157.5 from 159.5` are a positive `2` as well, while for your `y-diff`'s you have both negative and positive values. If you desire absolute values consider wrapping `xdiff` and `ydiff` into `abs()` in below code:

Nevertheless, with base R without loops you could do:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
x        y    
159.5    143.5
157.5    180.5
127.5    159.5
190.5    198.5
115.5    115.5
179.5    101.5
97.5     103.5
149.5    397.5", h = T)

df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(df$x, each = dim(df)[1]),
                  y = rep(df$y, each = dim(df)[1]),
                  xdiff = c(sapply(df$x, function(i) i - df$x)),
                  ydiff = c(sapply(df$y, function(j) j - df$y)),
                  fromx = rep(df$x, dim(df)[1]),
                  fromy = rep(df$y, dim(df)[1]))

       x     y xdiff ydiff fromx fromy
1  159.5 143.5     0     0 159.5 143.5
2  159.5 143.5     2   -37 157.5 180.5
3  159.5 143.5    32   -16 127.5 159.5
4  159.5 143.5   -31   -55 190.5 198.5
5  159.5 143.5    44    28 115.5 115.5
6  159.5 143.5   -20    42 179.5 101.5
7  159.5 143.5    62    40  97.5 103.5
8  159.5 143.5    10  -254 149.5 397.5
9  157.5 180.5    -2    37 159.5 143.5
10 157.5 180.5     0     0 157.5 180.5
11 157.5 180.5    30    21 127.5 159.5
12 157.5 180.5   -33   -18 190.5 198.5
13 157.5 180.5    42    65 115.5 115.5
14 157.5 180.5   -22    79 179.5 101.5
15 157.5 180.5    60    77  97.5 103.5
16 157.5 180.5     8  -217 149.5 397.5
17 127.5 159.5   -32    16 159.5 143.5
18 127.5 159.5   -30   -21 157.5 180.5
19 127.5 159.5     0     0 127.5 159.5
20 127.5 159.5   -63   -39 190.5 198.5
21 127.5 159.5    12    44 115.5 115.5
22 127.5 159.5   -52    58 179.5 101.5
23 127.5 159.5    30    56  97.5 103.5
24 127.5 159.5   -22  -238 149.5 397.5
25 190.5 198.5    31    55 159.5 143.5
26 190.5 198.5    33    18 157.5 180.5
27 190.5 198.5    63    39 127.5 159.5
28 190.5 198.5     0     0 190.5 198.5
29 190.5 198.5    75    83 115.5 115.5
30 190.5 198.5    11    97 179.5 101.5
31 190.5 198.5    93    95  97.5 103.5
32 190.5 198.5    41  -199 149.5 397.5
33 115.5 115.5   -44   -28 159.5 143.5
34 115.5 115.5   -42   -65 157.5 180.5
35 115.5 115.5   -12   -44 127.5 159.5
36 115.5 115.5   -75   -83 190.5 198.5
37 115.5 115.5     0     0 115.5 115.5
38 115.5 115.5   -64    14 179.5 101.5
39 115.5 115.5    18    12  97.5 103.5
40 115.5 115.5   -34  -282 149.5 397.5
41 179.5 101.5    20   -42 159.5 143.5
42 179.5 101.5    22   -79 157.5 180.5
43 179.5 101.5    52   -58 127.5 159.5
44 179.5 101.5   -11   -97 190.5 198.5
45 179.5 101.5    64   -14 115.5 115.5
46 179.5 101.5     0     0 179.5 101.5
47 179.5 101.5    82    -2  97.5 103.5
48 179.5 101.5    30  -296 149.5 397.5
49  97.5 103.5   -62   -40 159.5 143.5
50  97.5 103.5   -60   -77 157.5 180.5
51  97.5 103.5   -30   -56 127.5 159.5
52  97.5 103.5   -93   -95 190.5 198.5
53  97.5 103.5   -18   -12 115.5 115.5
54  97.5 103.5   -82     2 179.5 101.5
55  97.5 103.5     0     0  97.5 103.5
56  97.5 103.5   -52  -294 149.5 397.5
57 149.5 397.5   -10   254 159.5 143.5
58 149.5 397.5    -8   217 157.5 180.5
59 149.5 397.5    22   238 127.5 159.5
60 149.5 397.5   -41   199 190.5 198.5
61 149.5 397.5    34   282 115.5 115.5
62 149.5 397.5   -30   296 179.5 101.5
63 149.5 397.5    52   294  97.5 103.5
64 149.5 397.5     0     0 149.5 397.5
```

If you like, you could consider to delete the rows where `x == fromx` and `y == fromy` by doing `df2[!c(df2$x == df2$fromx & df2$y == df2$fromy),]`

Comment: Just edited the post. Is there a way to get the answer to work with a category variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a set of all differences built with `outer` and `expand.grid`:

```
cbind(cbind(with(dat, expand.grid(x=x,x=x)), xdiff=-c( with(dat, outer(x,x,"-") ))),
    cbind( with(dat, expand.grid(y=y,y=y)), ydiff=-c( with(dat, outer(y,y,"-") ))))

#-----------
       x     x xdiff     y     y ydiff
1  159.5 159.5     0 143.5 143.5     0
2  157.5 159.5     2 180.5 143.5   -37
3  127.5 159.5    32 159.5 143.5   -16
4  190.5 159.5   -31 198.5 143.5   -55
5  115.5 159.5    44 115.5 143.5    28
6  179.5 159.5   -20 101.5 143.5    42
7   97.5 159.5    62 103.5 143.5    40
8  149.5 159.5    10 397.5 143.5  -254
9  159.5 157.5    -2 143.5 180.5    37
10 157.5 157.5     0 180.5 180.5     0
11 127.5 157.5    30 159.5 180.5    21
12 190.5 157.5   -33 198.5 180.5   -18
13 115.5 157.5    42 115.5 180.5    65
14 179.5 157.5   -22 101.5 180.5    79
  #----snipped rest of 68 rows
```